# TestNG dataprovider skip after fail

Tags: java, testing, testng, dataprovider

For example I have code for test

```
@Test(dataprovider = "getData")
public void test(String data) {
    //perform some action using 'data'
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] getData(){
    return new Object[][]{
        {"One"},
        {"Two"},
        {"Three"},
        {"Four"},
        {"Five"}
    };      
}
```

For example test with data {"Three"} will be failed.
I need that tests for  {"Four"}, {"Five"} will skipped or failed(if {"Three"} was failed).
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: This solution will not work when you try to run your data driven tests in parallel. This will only work if you run your data driven tests in sequential order.**

Here's how you can do this.

1. Make sure you are using TestNG `7.0.0-beta1` (This is the latest released version as of today Dec 16 2018)
2. Have your test class implement `org.testng.IHookable` interface.
3. Now within the `run()` method set a boolean flag to indicate that downstream methods should be failed, if you found an exception (TestNG by default marks a test method as failed if it raises an exception)

Below is a sample that shows all of this in action.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.IHookCallBack;
import org.testng.IHookable;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Listeners(TestReporter.class)
public class TestclassExample implements IHookable {
  private boolean hasFailures = false;

  @Test(dataProvider = "getData")
  public void test(String data) {
    if (data.equals("Three")) {
      Assert.fail("Simulating a failure for [" + data + "]");
    }
    System.err.println("executing test  for data [" + data + "]");
  }

  @DataProvider
  public Object[][] getData() {
    return new Object[][] {{"One"}, {"Two"}, {"Three"}, {"Four"}, {"Five"}};
  }

  @Override
  public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {
    if (hasFailures) {
      testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
    } else {
      callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
      if (testResult.getThrowable() != null) {
        hasFailures = true;
      }
    }
  }

  public static class TestReporter implements ITestListener {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
      String msg =
          String.format(
              "[%s()] failed for data %s",
              result.getMethod().getMethodName(), Arrays.toString(result.getParameters()));
      System.err.println(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the output for the above code execution.

```
executing test  for data [One]
executing test  for data [Two]
[test()] failed for data [Three]

[test()] failed for data [Four]

[test()] failed for data [Five]

java.lang.AssertionError: Simulating a failure for [Three]

    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:97)
    at com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn53781839.TestclassExample.test(TestclassExample.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:237)
    at com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn53781839.TestclassExample.run(TestclassExample.java:36)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:249)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:654)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:792)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1103)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:140)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:739)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:589)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:398)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:392)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:302)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1145)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:997)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:965)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)


===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 5, Passes: 2, Failures: 3, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps me.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way. You can declare an `@AfterMethod` method with a `ITestResult` parameter -- this parameter will get auto-injected with the test result. Call `isSuccess()` to see if the method passed or failed. You can then do whatever you want with that information, such as causing future tests to be skipped by throwing a `SkipException`.

```java
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

public class TestTest {

    boolean hasFailures = false;

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            hasFailures = true;
        }
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] params() {
        return new Object[][] {
            { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 }, { 5 },
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "params")
    public void test(Integer n) {
        if (hasFailures) {
            throw new SkipException("a previous test failed");
        }
        if (n == 2) {
            fail();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
PASSED: TestTest.test(1)
FAILED: TestTest.test(2)
<stack trace omitted>

SKIPPED: TestTest.test(3)
org.testng.SkipException: a previous test failed
<stack trace omitted>

SKIPPED: TestTest.test(4)
org.testng.SkipException: a previous test failed
<stack trace omitted>

SKIPPED: TestTest.test(5)
org.testng.SkipException: a previous test failed
<stack trace omitted>

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 3
===============================================

===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 5, Passes: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 3
===============================================
```